# Do access modifiers work for static class functions?

Tags: c++, static-methods, access-modifiers

I just came across code that had `protected` static class functions, as in:

```
class C {
...

    protected:
        static int fun() { ... }
};
```

I got curious if static class functions could have access modifiers and what would it mean? Since they are class globals and not pre-instance.

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access modifiers in C++ do not work *per-instance*. They always work *per-class*. That is how it's always been. Which makes it perfectly logical to have them apply to static members as well.

It is a rather popular misconception that access protection in C++ is somehow supposed to work per-instance, which seems to be what inspired your question as well.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. Believe or not, I thought they were `per-instance`! A very serious mistake in my learning process. Now I know that they are `per-class`.

Answer (score 0):

It still serves the same purpose: Only derived classes can call that static function.

Comment: Oh? I thought static class functions always were accessible, no matter what.

Comment: static just means they're accessible without an instance of the object available. They have effectively global scope, but they still obey access restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

It means protected: static functions can be accessed from other member functions of that class or from the member functions of the derived classes.